# Voice input on Watch app

Tags: iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

i am working on app having functionality of taking voice input.So any one tell me how to take voice input within the watch application. Is is possible using siri or any other option??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:preset:maximumDuration:actionTitle:completion:`

It creates an interface to allow you to record audio from your AppleWatch device.

**Official documentation from Apple site:**

> Recording Short Audio Clips
>
> To record short audio clips, use the
>   presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:preset:maximumDuration:actionTitle:completion:
>   method of WKInterfaceController to display the standard audio
>   recording interface. When presenting the interface, you specify the
>   audio quality you want and the location for the resulting audio file.
>   After the user has recorded the content, the user must explicitly
>   accept the recording before it is written to disk at the URL you
>   specified.
>
> For information about the audio recording options, see the description
>   of the
>   presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:preset:maximumDuration:actionTitle:completion:
>   method in WKInterfaceController Class Reference.